# Logs inside io.on is not printing in server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

```
app.use("/api/message", messageRoute);
```

This is my API

```
router.post("/send", attachIOToRequest, sendMessageToUser);
```

This is my send Message route.

```
const { handleSocketEvents } = require("../utils/socketEvents");
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);

// Start the server and handle socket events
handleSocketEvents(io);

function attachIOToRequest(req, res, next) {
  req.io = io;
  next();
}

module.exports = {
  attachIOToRequest,
};
```

This is the middleware.

```
const messageController = require("../controllers/messageController");

let io;

exports.handleSocketEvents = async (socketIO) => {
  io = socketIO;
  console.log("Starting socket events!!!!");

  io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");

    socket.on("send_message", async (data) => {
      try {
        const message = await messageController.sendMessage(data);
        console.log("Message sent successfully using controller");
        console.log(message);
        io.to(data.receiverId).emit("message_sent", message);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending message:", error);
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
  });

  console.log("Socket event finished!!!!!");
};

exports.getIO = () => {
  return io;
};
```

This is handleSocket function . It is just printing , "Starting socket events!!!!" , "Socket event finished!!!!!" and anything inside io.on is not being printed , can you help me with this ?

Comment: Is it `io.sockets.on` or just `io.on`? Also it will only run when a socket connects to the server, check if the connection is working properly.